# Packaging WebForms ASCX Controls for Reuse

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I am trying to write some user controls that will potentially be reused across projects. However...

Let's say we want to write a control that will display a list of Foos in a `<div>`.

Consider this in the codebehind:

```
public partial class FooBar : UserControl
{
    protected List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Foos = Service.GetFoos();
    }
}
```

However I cannot then reference this property in the markup. I would expect this to work, but it will not compile:

```
<div>
<%
foreach (var i in Foos)
{ 
    %>
        <p>Name: <%: i.Name %></p>
    <%
}  
%>
</div>
```

Error given is:

```
'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'Foos'
```

I looked at using both WebServerControl and UserControl but neither seemed to let me 'design' (i.e use Markup) for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this sample code is not working (because it should and it is if copied to the clean project) but you can alternatively switch to the Repeater control if you are just planning to display data without any fancy transformations:

```
<div>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFoos">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>Name: <%#: Eval("Name") %></p>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And in codebehind:

```
public partial class FooBar : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptFoos.DataSource = Service.GetFoos();
        rptFoos.DataBind();
    }
}
```

As I said both ways are working for me on clean project but I think that if you will try to use repeater, maybe you will spot the problem quicker.

Comment: Was this in a Windows Library project or a Web App? It seems to work for me in a webapp but not in a Windows Library (after adding required references, namespaces etc.)

Comment: @glosrob it was in Web App. In my past I was following the guide http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/10/06/using-msbuild-and-ilmerge-to-package-user-controls-for-reuse.aspx and I had no issues.